# Unpivot SQL Table with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to unpivot a SQL table around multiple columns.
I have tried a normal UNPIVOT statement but that only ppivots around one value.
See this link for example: https://codingsight.com/understanding-pivot-unpivot-and-reverse-pivot-statements.

I have tried to illustrate my data as well as my desired outcome in the picture below.
The top table is a sample of the data in the SQL table. I have used 3 materials but in reality there are 20.

The bottom table is my desired outcome.

The data is on a SQL 2008-r2 server.

Any pointers on how to go about this task?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `cross apply`, like so:

```
select t.date, t.product, x.*
from mytable t
cross apply (values 
    (container1material, container1amount),
    (container2material, container2amount),
    (container3material, container3amount)
) x(material, amount)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply` for unpivoting:

```
select t.date, t.product, v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (container1amount, container1material),
             (container2amount, container2material),
             (container3amount, container3material)
     ) v(containeramount, containermaterial);
```

`unpivot` is bespoke syntax (not-standard) and it only does one thing.  By contrast, lateral joins are very powerful and unpivoting is only one thing that you can do with them.  `Apply` is worth learning about.